# Bokeh CustomJS hover over to recolor

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs

I'm fairly good with Python but new to Bokeh as well as javascript. I'm trying to achieve a hover over effect similar to the one seen in the [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-hover) for customjs for hover.
The catch is that aside from the effects in the example, I would *also* like the end-points `(x1, y1)` to change color when I hover over the start-point `(x0, y0)`.
I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement this, any inputs or good hint?